# get comma seperated arrays from foreach

Tags: php, arrays

array i have now is :

```
        Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [title] => "product name 1"
                [price] => 600
                [quantity] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [title] => "product name"
                [price] => 600
                [quantity] => 1
            )

    )
```

What i need to achieve is this

```
array(
      array(
            "title"=> "product name 1",
            "price"=> 600,
            "quantity"=> 1
            ),
        array(
            "title"=> "product name 2",
            "price"=> 600,
            "quantity"=> 1
            )
    )
```

**Edited** : Var export of the first array is

```
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        'title' => 'Eames Replica DSR plastic side chair - White',
        'quantity' => '4',
        'price' => '54.0000',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        'title' => '3 Year Warranty',
        'quantity' => '4',
        'price' => '0.0000',
      ),
    )
```

Comment: Looking for [`var_export`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php)?

Comment: What code are you using for this output ?

Comment: Rather for `foreach`, `is_array`, `echo` and recurrency

Comment: @Siguza i have varexported array 1

Comment: @VikrantVirBhalla i have added var_dump array of array 1. and second one is what i need to achieve.

Comment: @SumanK.C And from what I can tell, that output is equivalent to the one you're looking for...

Comment: Are you trying to store the output to a PHP script?

Comment: No, i figured it out it's same. i was working to have without index. Thanks alot.

Answer (score -1):

I have created this sample code Please try and let me know

```
<?php 
$arr = array (1, 2, array ("a", "b", "c"));
$export = preg_replace('(\d+\s=>)', "", var_export($arr, true));
echo "<pre>"; print_r($export);
?>
```

It is giving me the following output

```
array (
   1,
   2,

  array (
     'a',
     'b',
     'c',
  ),
)
```